# How can I print text of a page in Persian by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi this is my code:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> url="http://localhost:8000/GetDetailsItem.html"
>>> content=requests.get(url)
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(content.text)
>>> print(soup)
```

Then, I print it and it like as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport"/>
<title>Ø³Ø§Ù…Ø§Ù†Ù‡ Ø«Ø¨Øª Ø§Ø·Ù„Ø§Ø¹Ø§Øª Ø§Ù…Ù„Ø§Ú© Ú©Ø´ÙˆØ±</title>
<link href="/Component/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

As you can see above some parts is strange
how can i fix this error?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to look into the HTML page, to see whether it has a declared charset, or to try to look at it in a browser still to find its declared charset.

A little *guess and try* with the current output let think that there was somewhere an UTF-8 encoded byte string that was erroneously decoded as cp1252. Because:

```
print('Ø³Ø§Ù…Ø§Ù†Ù‡ Ø«Ø¨Øª Ø§Ø·Ù„Ø§Ø¹Ø§Øª Ø§Ù…Ù„Ø§Ú© Ú©Ø´ÙˆØ±'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8'))
```

gives:

```
سامانه ثبت اطلاعات املاک کشور
```

So you just have to declare the encoding:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> url="http://localhost:8000/GetDetailsItem.html"
>>> content=requests.get(url)
>>> content.encoding = 'utf8'         # declare the page encoding
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(content.text)
>>> print(soup)
```

You should get:

```
...
<title>سامانه ثبت اطلاعات املاک کشور</title>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an encoding problem.

I think adding `from_encoding='utf-8'` may help you:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(content.text, from_encoding='utf-8')
```

something to read:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/beautiful_soup/beautiful_soup_encoding.htm